# My C++ prime number identifier and prime factor finder has a bug

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner to C++ and this website, so any dumb mistakes are out of ignorance. For practice, I'm trying to write a program that identifies a prime number and gives a composite's prime factors if the user requests. The prime IDer works, but the prime factors do not. When I type in twelve as my number, it gives me the factors 2 3 and 5, and 12's prime factors are 2 2 and 3. What am I messing up? Here is the code. Don't mind the weird spaces or names.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

//Printing factors help
void print(std::vector<int> const& factors)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < factors.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << factors.at(i) << ' ';
    }
}


int main() {

    //Restarting it
    std::string again;
    again = "Yes";

    //Actual loop
    while (again == "Yes") {

        //Variable/vectors
        std::string pfacts;
        double input = 0;
        double result = 0;
        double looper = 2;
        int looper2 = 2;
        int printed = 0;
        int printed2 = 0;

        std::vector<int> factors;
        std::vector<int> holders;

        //Asking for number
        std::cout << "Please enter your number.\n";
        std::cin >> input;
        double holder = input;

        //Ratting out trolls
        if (input == 0) {
            std::cout << "Your number is neither.\n";
            looper = 1000003;
        }

        if (input == 1) {
            std::cout << "Your number is neither.\n";
            looper = 1000003;
        }


        //Prime/composite loop
        while (looper < 1000002 and input != 1 and fmod(result, 1) == 0) {
            result = input / looper;

            //Finding composite
            if (fmod(result, 1) == 0 and printed == 0) {
                std::cout << "Your number is composite.\n";
                printed = 1;
                looper = 1000003;
            }

            //Finding prime
            else if (fmod(result, 1) != 0 and printed2 == 0) {
                std::cout << "Your number is prime.\n";
                printed2 = 1;
            }

        }

        //Asking about factors
        if (printed == 1) {
            std::cout << "Would you like to know it's prime factors? (Please type Yes or No exactly)\n";
            std::cin >> pfacts;
        }

        //Actually finding them
        if (pfacts == "Yes") {
            while (looper2 < 1000002) {

                if (holder / looper2 == 0) {
                    factors.push_back(holder);
                    looper2 = 1000003;
                }

                if (looper2 < 1000002 and fmod  (fmod(holder, looper2),   1) == 0 and looper2 % 2 != 0 or looper2 / 2 == 1) {
                    factors.push_back(looper2);
                    holder = holder / looper2;
                }
                looper2 = looper2 + 1;
            }

            //Printing them
            print(factors);
            std::cout << "\n";


        }













        //Again?
        std::cout << "Do you need to input another number? (Please type, exactly: Yes or No)\n";
        std::cin >> again;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why is this code using `double`s values, when `int`s will perfectly suffice, and why does the shown code spends a dozen lines of code, highlighted by a `while` loop, simply to check if a given number is even, when this elementary task can be accomplished by just a single line of code? It shouldn't take more than, oh, a few dozen lines of codes to do this task, instead of all of this. This is way over-engineered.

Comment: Algorithm trouble. You can't know whether the number is prime until you've finished trying to find factors for it. You can't possibly know it inside the loop.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info)

Comment: _"Don't mind the weird spaces or names."_ -- Not a problem. I'll stop reading the question and move on to the next without answering. *(If you want to get more people interested in answering your question, please take the time to present your [mre] well.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just making a really simple thing more complex with that looper , printed stuff,
a good programmer is one which solves hard things in easy way. 
So it is hard to understand for me to know exactly what you're doing in the code above at least not without enough comments.

So here is my solution, i am just providing the algorithm so you can write your own code and learn from it.

First note things below.

1. A prime number is a positive integer which has exactly two factors first is 1 and another is that number itself , so two is smallest prime number.
2. A number is also prime if it is not divisible from 2 to its square root, you should consider this fact for performance.

Now the algorithm:

1. Take the number in a variable `num`.
2. Check if it is positive integer greater then 1, if not then it is not a prime.
3. Take `num`'s squareroot with help of `sqrt()` function in variable `num` as you don't need original `num` any more.
4. Now add one to `num`  and take its absolute value.
5. Start a loop from `i = 2` to `num`: you're starting from 2 because two is the smallest prime.
6. In every iteration check `num % i == 0`, if yes then it is not a prime and you break, otherwise don't do anything.
7. Now after the loop ends check if `i == num`, if yes that means you never broke the hence the number is prime and you're done, otherwise you broke the loop hence the number is not prime and you ask for prime factors.
8. Now again you start from `j = 2` to `num`.
9. Now if `num % j == 0`, you print `j` and do `num = num / j`, otherwise you increment `j`.

I hope it is helpful. I didn't test it on an IDE, because I don't have one because I don't write c++ code anymore. Tell me if you find any bugs.

Comment: This doesn't work. Try again. The statement that 'you don't need original `num` any more' is false, and taking the absolute value of a value that can't be negative is futile. And please lay off the screaming boldface. It doesn't help.

Comment: sorry by absolute value i mean remove the digit after point from the result of sqrl(num) , you can just put it in an int for that purpose, and i did't think that you need the original number to find out the prime factor so i said you don't need original anymore, you actually don't need it anymore if you just want to find out weather it was prime or not.

Comment: you can also skip the whole sqrt thing if you only care about the answer , it is for performance  in case you are checking for a really big number.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really needed that help.

Comment: if it worked can you please upvote my answer